# [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'dbname'

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have a form with a textarea field that has about 250k of html in it. I'm posting it to an ASP page that is calling a stored procedure and inserting the text into a table. The field type and stored procedure parameter are both varchar(max). This page works fine when I post smaller html sets but give me the error.

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'dbname'
```

when I use large HTML data sets. Any ideas what the problem is?

ASP

```
Dim addRS, addCMD
Set addCMD = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
addCMD.ActiveConnection = objconn
ddCMD.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
addCMD.CommandText = "insert_emailjob"

addCMD.Parameters.Append(addCMD.CreateParameter("emailbody",adlongVarchar,adParamInput,10000000,emailbody))

set addRS = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
addRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
addRS.open addCMD
```

PROC

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_emailjob]
   @emailbody as varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO emails (emailbody) VALUES (@emailbody)
END
```

Comment: If you call the stored procedure in Query Analyzer using a large HTML set, do you get any other errors besides that one?  Do you get the error above?

Comment: Thats bizare.  You are using a parameterised command object not using string concatenation to build SQL?  Show some of the code.

Comment: post some specific code. to discard possibilities

Comment: there is my asp call to my proce and my proc code. Pretty simple. I'll try inserting via ssms per LittleBobbyTables recommendation.

Comment: When I insert it calling the proc within ssms it works fine. SO it's IIS or the Driver or the ASP proc call.

Answer (score 0):

there is a default iis limit of uploading more than 100k in one form field

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996475(v=exchg.80)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996475%28v=exchg.80%29)